# How to reset BIOS F.60 on HP Laptop 15-bs111ur?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, fan, hp-pavilion

A couple of months ago I updated BIOS of my **HP Laptop 15-bs111ur** on **F.60**. I am sure that I downloaded F.60 from the [official website](https://support.hp.com/ua-ru/drivers/selfservice/hp-15-bs100-laptop-pc/16851388/model/18477279?sku=2PP31EA). Around the same time, after BIOS upgrading I started to hear **loud fan noise**. I performed many steps to fix it:

1. Updated all drivers;
2. Reinstalled Windows 10 Home Edition;
3. Used all tests from HP Support Assistant;
4. Thermal paste was replaced;
5. **The fan was replaced (yes, I even installed a new fan for CPU).**

Nothing helped.

---

Recently, I noticed, that **F.60 version was gone** from the [list of versions supported for my bs-111ur](https://support.hp.com/ua-ru/drivers/selfservice/hp-15-bs100-laptop-pc/16851388/model/18477279?sku=2PP31EA). And now, obviously, I am pretty sure BIOS should be reset. I tried to reset BIOS with the following ways:

- [**Reset a laptop with a removable battery**](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c01684768);
- **Win+B+Power button**: HP BIOS Update screen does not display;
- **Reset the CMOS** using Win+V+Power button: reset was successfully executed.
  However,  BIOS is still F.60 version, and I am still can not reset it via "Win+B+Power button".
- [**Recover the BIOS using a USB recovery drive**](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c02693833#usbrecovery): HP BIOS Update does
  not display.

How I can reset BIOS? Or maybe there is some way to downgrade F.60 on F.52?

Comment: reset and downgrade are completely different things, don't confuse them. Otherwise, I can't respond substantially, but I've upvoted the question.

Comment: Those are the only 2 methods for recovery or downgrade on an HP, it will have to go to a HP service center if you want it done.